# To understand realloc

Tags: c++, realloc

I am doing some experiment to understand the realloc function in cpp. 
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


class node 
{
public:
    int value;
    int count;

    node(void)
    {
        count=5;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    node **n=(node**)malloc(3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        n[i]=new node();
        cin>>n[i]->value;
    }
    n=(node **)realloc(n,5);
    n[3]=new node();
    cin>>n[3]->value;
    n[4]=new node();
    cin>>n[4]->value;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<n[i]->value<<"\t"<<n[i]->count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter the values, all the nodes are printed exactly except first one, in which it is printing some address and the value zero.

Why is this happening? 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Don't use `malloc` or `realloc` in C++. They are for C, and internally `new` is often (but that is implementation dependent) calling `malloc` (and of course `delete` would call `free`). Use only `new` & `delete` in C++, preferably implicitly by using *smart pointers*

Comment: @Kam probably because this is not C++

Answer (score 3):

Like the comments say, malloc and realloc aren't really C++ - a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` is what this would be in C++.

That said, what you're doing should work (as you're allocating an array of pointers to objects, not objects, so malloc/realloc is allowed), except you're missing one bit:

You're only allocating 3 bytes of memory, not 3 pointers. You need:

```
node **n=(node**)malloc(3 * sizeof(Node*));
```

and

```
n=(node **)realloc(n,5 * sizeof(Node*));
```